# stringByAppendingString issues in objective c

Tags: objective-c

```
NSString *tmpStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
xmlSms = [xmlSms stringByAppendingString:tmpStr];
NSLog(xmlSms);
```

I got code above but `NSLog` doesn't show anything... Anybody know the problem??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

nevermind... i figured out why.
The problem is, when you want to use stringByAppendingString on a string, the string should have initial value.

Wrong example:

```
NSString *str1;
str1 = [str1 stringByAppendingString:@"test"];
```

Should be:

```
NSString *str1 = @"";
str1 = [str1 stringByAppendingString:@"test"];
```

Answer (score 4):

Your call to NSLog is not correct. Try:

```
NSLog(@"%@", xmlSms);
```

Comment: To expand, `%@` is the format specifier for an object in the `NSLog()` format string, which applies to `NSString` instances since they are objects. The string format specifiers are explained here: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265

Comment: It is not the issue, I already check the xmlSms length and it showed 0. And nslog(xmlsms) Should be worked too as Ive did it many time. The problem is why appendingstring doesn't worked

Comment: How do you create xmlSms? Can you show the code for that variable?

Answer (score 0):

In Cocoa, initialization functions ("constructors") often return `nil` if they fail for some reason or another. The documentation for [`NSString`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithData:encoding:) states:

> Returns nil if the initialization fails for some reason (for example if data does not represent valid data for encoding).

Are you sure the `NSData` object passed to the init function actually contains a UTF8-encoded string? If it doesn't, the returned object will be `nil`.

Comment: Yes, NSString *tmpStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
Is that what you mean?

I think the problem is about this, xmlSms = [xmlSms stringByAppendingString:tmpStr];
But i can't figure out why it doesn't worked..